# Is it possible to load all my javascripts dynamically using googlecode

Tags: google-code

My site using heavy javascripts. So can i upload them in google code and load them dynamically like loading jquery from google for speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free hosting for web content is against the [terms of service of Google Code](http://code.google.com/projecthosting/policy.html) and people have been banned for using it in this way.

> **12. Generic File Hosting:** Google Project Hosting is meant for the facilitation of software development and the storage of artifacts related to software development. Storage of data that is not relevant to software development is not allowed without the express permission of Google.